# Combine Vertical scoll view of parent layout and contents of view pager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a 'page' that has a number of components on it, and who's content is longer than the height of the device. one of the component is view pager. Content of view pager is also very large.  How can i combine vertical scroll view of parent layout and view pager layout.My laytout is as follows:

few components

view pager-(large content in another layout)

few more component

i want to combine scroll view of view pager and parent layout

Comment: u want to view pager inside scroll view?????

Comment: i'm not sure what you are trying to do, do you want a listview inside a viewpager? then try the `ListFragment`

Comment: i have some more components out side view pager. so i need scroll view for contnts inside view pager and out side of view pager. i have given heiht of view pager as wrap content..but it shows only one line content. ineed to scrollinside view pager

Comment: i mean i need to show full content of view pager then that static content of page.. user should feel only one scroll view

Comment: try to height of view pager like "20dp" or as per ur requirment

Comment: If i have give like 20 dp.. i will get 2 scrolling.. inside view pager and out side view pager..but i need only one scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just work. See here -> [ViewPager inside a ScrollView does not scroll correclty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381697/viewpager-inside-a-scrollview-does-not-scroll-correclty)

You structure should be like this:

```
ScrollView
-ViewPager
--ScrollView
```

Then just apply the suggestions made in the linked post above.

**Also make sure the ViewPager has a fixed height!** Otherwise the ScrollView inside the ViewPager won't work without writing a custom ScrollView or ViewPager.

Comment: inside my view pager also large content.. so what to do

Comment: If the "large content" is inside a scroll view you should not have a problem.

Comment: You have said to  make sure the ViewPager has a fixed height! Otherwise the ScrollView inside the ViewPager wont work. here is the problem. i cant tell the view pager height.... It is dynamic content

Comment: In this case you need to write a custom ViewPager or ScrollView as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut/8483078#8483078

Comment: ok thank you . Problem is fixed by creating custom view pager and scroll view