# NestedScrollView in fragment with TabLayout & ViewPager not able to scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-tablayout

I added NestedScrollView into my fragment as following code snippet.

I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter to display fragment content in ViewPager. (following [this article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout))

Content is populating properly but I'm not able to scroll.

**main_fragment.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@color/feed_grey_background" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_gap_1_5x">
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**tabview_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/postList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**update**

I'm able to scroll recycler view (not nestedscrollview) if I remove `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14435116/3734116

Comment: @Andev No luck.

Comment: Then it has to be something like --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/2655740/3734116. The simplest solution though is to prevent nested scrolling elements.

Comment: @Andev Thanks for sharing but my requirement changed and I'm not using that layout anymore. I will check it and update here when I get time.