# ScrollView doesn't scroll in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager, scrollview

In my app I use a TabLayout under a Toolbar, and a ViewPager filling the rest of the space. I need one of the fragments under the tab to be able to scroll. tried using ScrollView, NestedScrollView and android:fillViewport="true" with no success.

I've looked at other questions about the same problem, tried anything that was suggested in the answers, but they all didn't solve my problem.

the activity that contains the ViewPager's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".UserProfile">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/userToolbar"
        layout="@layout/user_info_toolbar_layout" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userToolbar"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/dashboardTab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dashboard_tab_text_en" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/statisticsTab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/statistics_tab_text_en" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/userInfoViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tabLayout" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the fragment's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/user_dashboard_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".Dashboard">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/userInfoContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.github.abdularis.civ.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/userImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/male_user_sample1"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/username_sample"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userImage" />

        <com.ramijemli.percentagechartview.PercentageChartView
            android:id="@+id/userLevelProgress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"
            app:pcv_animDuration="1000"
            app:pcv_animInterpolator="anticipate_overshoot"
            app:pcv_drawBackground="false"
            app:pcv_drawBackgroundBar="false"
            app:pcv_mode="ring"
            app:pcv_orientation="counter_clockwise"
            app:pcv_progress="100"
            app:pcv_startAngle="270"
            app:pcv_textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:pcv_textShadowRadius="100"
            app:pcv_textSize="50sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userLevel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/level_sample"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userLevelProgress" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I can't find the problem in my code that causes the fragment under the ViewPager being unscrollable.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381697/viewpager-inside-a-scrollview-does-not-scroll-correclty Your viewpager scroll listener is conflicting with your ScrollView, probably

Comment: @W0rmH0le I did check this one, solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rty this

In your `ViewPager`

```
 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/userInfoViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"                          // <- ****
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"      // <- ****
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tablayout"
 />
```

Then, in fragment xml

```
<ScrollView
    ....
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  // <- ****
   >

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/userInfoContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" // <- ****
    >
```

Comment: Yes!!!! It worked!! thank you so much, I was stuck on this for too long

Comment: @IronMan Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

it's seems like there some bug with `ConstraintLayout` inside `ScrollView` ,Don't forget that If you constraint some view's bottom to constraint layout's bottom. `Scrollview` could not scroll. Use `NestedScrollView` with viewport true is working good for me

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        ......
        ......
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```