# Android : ScrollView + ViewPager doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, pagertabstrip

In my android application, I want to implement `PagerSlidingTab and ViewPager` inside `ScrollView`. The layout file is shown below. I am facing a weird problem in that. It shows only tab strip on top and no content is displayed for `ViewPager` Fragment content on screen. I don't know what is the problem with that. If I remove ScreollView from layout then it works perfectly but I want everything inside `ScrollView`. Please help me to solve this issue.

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.danzim.diamond.classes.KenBurnsView
            android:id="@+id/newsHeaderKenburn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/newsTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newsHeaderKenburn"
            android:background="@drawable/background_news_tab"
            app:pstsDividerColor="@color/transparent"
            app:pstsIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:pstsTextAllCaps="true" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/newsPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newsTabs" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried that the RelativeLayout size wrap the content instead of match the parent ?

Comment: @Hacketo yes, i have tried that.its not working

Answer (score 5):

There was a minor mistake in my code. I changed the `ScrollView` code and its working properly.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Just need to add  `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView` element. I got the answer from this link: [Is it possible to have a ViewPager inside of a ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381360/is-it-possible-to-have-a-viewpager-inside-of-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution would be to add android:fillViewport="true" to your scroll view but there is a deeper problem in using this layout to consider.

The problem you are having is that the ScrollView wraps its content and takes "ownership" of the resizing of the elements inside of it. So it resizes the Relative layout to only fit in the headers of the PagerSlidingTabStrip cause that is all the information it has when it does the layout for the screen. The contents of the ViewPager has not been added yet so it doesn't take that into consideration when resizing the relative layout.

Suggested solution is to have the scrollview inside of each of the elements that will be inside the viewPager Control. So you are going to be adding fragments to the ViewPage i assume? just make sure that the ScrollView is the topMost control in each of those layouts. It makes for less unexpected behaviour later on when you want to put for example a listview inside the ViewPager, ListViews and ScrollViews dont like each other and you can only have one or the other you cant have anything else that scrolls inside the ScrollView.

Hope this has helped you out at least. Please ping me if you need more information about this.

Comment: yaa, i got that solution but i have to put viewpager inside `ScrollView` as i want functionality of scrolling entire page, that page can have anything like, `ViewPager` and other controls. So i am using ScrollView outside ViewPager. Thanks for your replay.

Comment: ok cool just thought that i would point out that you wont be able to use listviews of anything else that uses the scroll feature inside the fragments that are going to be used in the view pager later on :). The fillViewport = true part will at least make sure that the scrollview will fill all available space on the screen instead of just re-sizing the contents

Comment: So there is no way to make the whole view scrollable, when you have a viewpager with wrap_content in a scrollview ?

Comment: @AdrianoCelentano Sorry late to the party..but i am facing the same issue   when using Scrollview as root view inside fragments with viewpager..Did you found out solution to this problem?