# ViewPager not displayed in scrollview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, scrollbar

I have a group of view, which form a fragment. In this group there viewPager. FrameLayout, which is the fragment appears, lies in scrollview. There was a problem: for some reason viewPager in scrolling is not displayed. All elements of the group displayed, but viewPager is not. What could be the reason?

Comment: It helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381360/is-it-possible-to-have-a-viewpager-inside-of-a-scrollview?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write in your XML view ..**android:fillViewport="true"** it'll worked for me