# Viewpager inside scrollview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-viewpager, adt

I have a `ViewPager` Inside a `ScrollView` along with other components. When I give a height to `ViewPager` in `XML` then the `ScrollView` works normally but I cant give height for `ScrollView` as the `ViewPager` should expand according to the page height. I have implemented a runnable which will expand the `ViewPager` on runtime.

The problem is I am not able to scroll the outer `ScrollView` which is holding the `ViewPager`

XML =======

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/img1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/img_1"
    />
<ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
</ViewPager>
</ScrollView>
```

JAVA to dynamically set height for viewpager

```
viewpager.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = viewpager.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = viewpager.getChildAt(viewpager.getCurrentItem()).getHeight();
    viewpager.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

});

Comment: Please provide us your code to help you

Comment: Did you get a way to do it?

Comment: nvm I got it, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32410274/1332549)

Comment: Please show my answer in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381360/is-it-possible-to-have-a-viewpager-inside-of-a-scrollview/43987753#43987753

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered here: [Dynamic height viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32410274/1332549).

Anyway I'm going to give you the code that you need to solve it:

```
public class CustomPager extends ViewPager {

    private View mCurrentView;

    public CustomPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mCurrentView == null) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        mCurrentView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = mCurrentView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h > height) height = h;
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void measureCurrentView(View currentView) {
        mCurrentView = currentView;
        requestLayout();
    }

    public int measureFragment(View view) {
        if (view == null)
            return 0;

        view.measure(0, 0);
        return view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

Like owner's answers said:

> ViewPager needs to be re-measured each time a page is changed. Good place to do this is setPrimaryItem function of PagerAdapter

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private int mCurrentPosition = -1;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new FirstFragment());
        fragments.add(new SecondFragment());
        fragments.add(new ThirdFragment());
        fragments.add(new FourthFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        if (position != mCurrentPosition) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
            CustomPager pager = (CustomPager) container;
            if (fragment != null && fragment.getView() != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = position;
                pager.measureCurrentView(fragment.getView());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

You can find all code [here](https://github.com/vabhishek/WrapContentViewPagerDemo)

Answer (score 1):

I found good solution [here](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Solving-ViewPager-Height-Issue-Inside-A-Scrollview)

Anyway, it is code from article:

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        try {
            int currentPagePosition=0;
            View child = getChildAt(currentPagePosition);
            if (child != null) {
                child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

You need to create your own custom view pager extended from ViewPager and override onMeasure method

Answer (score -1):

I think you must remove your java code. but add this properties to your scrollview xml:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: I'm guessing viewPager content is defined at runtime or downloaded so he can't use fillViewport.