# ViewPager inside ScrollView not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to put a `ViewPager` inside a `CoordinatorLayout` withing a `NestedScrollView`. The viewpager houses 3 fragments.

Problem is the fragments aren't visible. Tabs show up and the rest of the layout is visible and scrolls accordingly.

Below is the code for my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/DarkBodyBackground"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:background="@color/DarkBodyBackground"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <include layout="@layout/artist_header" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/loading_indicator" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="fixed" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Know it's silly, but are you handling `visibility = "gone"` ?

Comment: suggestion: coordintaor layout should be parent of xml

Comment: @not_again_stackoverflow I am loading some content through a network call and toggle the visibility to `visible` after it's done loading.

Comment: @KanishR I need the toolbar to be fixed at the top and not scroll through with the rest of the content, hence the `CoordinatorLayout` is not the parent.

Comment: Does the `ViewPager` show up without `scrollView` ?

Comment: @not_again_stackoverflow Yes it does.

Comment: I'm guessing this should be able to help you fix your issue -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580954/viewpager-in-a-nestedscrollview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a ViewPager inside of a ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381360/is-it-possible-to-have-a-viewpager-inside-of-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try adding this piece of code before loading your `viewPager`

```
NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById (R.id.nest_scrollview);
scrollView.setFillViewport (true);
```

Let me know if it helped fix the issue.

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks!

Comment: You can specify it from XML also -> use android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, that worked and saved my hours

Answer (score 13):

Use `android:fillViewport="true"` in `ScrollView`

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer resulted in my fragments now being visible. However, it left me with the problem that my NestedScrollView would no longer scroll!

To overcome this, I have created a custom ViewPager (based on [this article](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Solving-ViewPager-Height-Issue-Inside-A-Scrollview)) that calculates it's height in the required manner.

Here is full code for my **CustomViewPager**:

```
package org.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViewPager(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        try {
            int numChildren = getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (child != null) {
                    child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                    int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                    heightMeasureSpec = Math.max(heightMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

In your layout xml, you'd then just replace `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` with `org.example.CustomViewPager`.

(I also removed the new `android:fillViewport="true"` attribute from my NestedScrollView element as it seems this is now no longer needed.)

Comment: Hi +1 for your solution. it is works!, but the problem is the margin bottom somehow is missing. How i can restore the margin bottom after onMeasure?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `ScrollView` and `NestedScroolview` Just use `SliderLayout` it will work perfectly.

1. add below dependency inside `build.gradle` (app level)

   ```
   implementation 'ru.noties:scrollable:1.3.0'
   ```
2. layout

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <include layout="@layout/toolbar" /> <!-- its toolbar -->
       <ru.noties.scrollable.ScrollableLayout
           android:id="@+id/scrollable_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:scrollable_autoMaxScroll="true"
           app:scrollable_defaultCloseUp="true">

           <!-- what ever you want you can add here, its like tabs header part -->
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:weightSum="1">

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imageViewProfilePic"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="60dp"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                   android:layout_weight=".75"
                   android:src="@drawable/hashtag" />

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                   android:layout_weight=".25"
                   android:orientation="vertical">

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/textviewTagName"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                       android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                       android:text=""
                       android:textColor="#000"
                       android:textSize="12sp"
                       android:textStyle="bold" />
                   />

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/textViewNoofPosts"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_below="@+id/textviewFollow"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                       android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                       android:text="(University name)"
                       android:textSize="11dp" />

               </LinearLayout>
           </LinearLayout>

           <!--
               <ru.noties.scrollable.sample.SampleHeaderView
                   style="@style/HeaderStyle"
                   app:shv_title="@string/sample_title_fragment_pager"/>
           -->

           <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
               android:id="@+id/tablayout"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
               app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/appcolor"
               app:tabMode="fixed"
               app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/appcolor" />

           <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
               android:id="@+id/viewpager"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

       </ru.noties.scrollable.ScrollableLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Activity code:

   ```
   public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       TabLayout tabLayout;
       private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
       private ViewPager mViewPager;


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);
           Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);//back arrow on toolbar
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

           mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

           mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
           mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
           tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
           tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
           if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
               onBackPressed();
           }

       }

       @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {
           this.finish();
           super.onBackPressed();
       }


       public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

           public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
               super(fm);
           }

           @Override
           public Fragment getItem(int position) {
               switch (position) {
                   case 0:
                       return new frag1();

                   case 1:
                       return new frag2();
               }
               return null;
           }

           @Override
           public int getCount() {
               // Show 2 total pages.
               return 2;
           }

           @Override
           public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
               switch (position) {
                   case 0:
                       return "one";
                   case 1:
                       return "two";
               }
               return null;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Use nestedScrollview and set the property of nestedscrollenabled as true and I think you will do it.

Comment: Thanks, Raj, but using `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` is only available from API 21, which is too high for me to try.

Answer (score -2):

So let me do it for you : the correct hierarchy as suggested by google blogspot it is working fine for me:Check this out

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/cl_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/coverimage"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabContentStart="72dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/my_cloud_tv"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

let me know if it helps