# Viewpager in Scrollview dose not work

Tags: android

In my project i have a **ViewPager** that display some image horizontally. I want to put it in a ScrollView but when I do this it dose not work.

here is my XML :

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.pixelcan.inkpageindicator.InkPageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:ipi_animationDuration="320"
            app:ipi_currentPageIndicatorColor="@android:color/black"
            app:ipi_dotDiameter="8dp"
            app:ipi_dotGap="8dp"
            app:ipi_pageIndicatorColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is my main :`

```js
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import com.pixelcan.inkpageindicator.InkPageIndicator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        InkPageIndicator inkPageIndicator = (InkPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        ArrayList<Model> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(new Model("image 1", R.drawable.baby1));
        values.add(new Model("image 2", R.drawable.baby2));
        values.add(new Model("image 3", R.drawable.baby3));
        values.add(new Model("image 4", R.drawable.baby4));

        View_Pager_Adapter adapter = new View_Pager_Adapter(values);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        inkPageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);


    }

}
```

I search a lot about this but non of them was useful for me.
please help me 
Thanks

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381360/is-it-possible-to-have-a-viewpager-inside-of-a-scrollview

Comment: give your viewpager fix height and it should work

Comment: Why you want to put viewpager inside scrollview ?? what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Share your `View_Pager_Adapter`

Comment: I have something else to show below this viewpager so I need a scrollview.

Comment: I give my viewpager a fix height and it work now.Thanks